# Distance between boundary and interior of a set is zero

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset E$ a nonempty subset of $E$.
Suppose that $int(A)$ and $\partial A$ are both nonempty. Then $$d(int(A),\partial A)=0$$

Aiming for a proof, let $k>0$ and $T$ the set $T=\{d(x,y)|x\in int(A), y\in \partial A\}$. For any $y\in \partial A$, we know that $B(y,k)\cap A\neq \emptyset$. If this implies that $B(y,k)\cap int(A)\neq \emptyset$, then we choose some $x\in int(A)$ such that $d(x,y)<k$. Therefore $k$ is not a lower bound of $T$, which implies that $d(int(A),\partial A)=\inf T=0$.

However, this argument is incomplete as I can't prove that last implication, nor find a counterexample. Is this statement false?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're essentially done.  Which last implication are you stuck on?  The last implication looks to have several pieces.

Comment: $B(y,k) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ implies $B(y,k) \cap int(A)\neq \emptyset$. Not really sure about it...

Comment: How does it imply the infimum is $0$?

Comment: Well, $0$ is already a lower bound of $T$ because the distances are nonnegative. So we want to prove that $0$ is the greatest lower bound.

Comment: Isn't $int(A)$ open by definition? Maybe use that.

Comment: Because $int(A)$ is open, $B(y,k)\cap int(A)$ is open. Does it help?

Comment: alex-- please "unaccept" my answer. I think I should delete it since it doesn't finish things, but cannot do so for an "accepted" answer.

Comment: As @Matematleta suggested, this should be useful:
$x \in \partial A$ iff given $r>0$, $B(x,r) \cap A\neq \emptyset$ and $B(x,r)\cap A^C \neq \emptyset$ iff $x\in \overline A$ and $B(x,r) \not\subseteq A$ iff $x\in \overline A$ and $x\not\in int(A)$ iff $x\in \overline A \setminus int(A)$.

Hence $\partial A = \overline A \setminus int(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on distance function, if we define the distance function to be $d(x,y)=\text{inf}_{x\in A^o}||x-y||$ such that $y \in \partial{A}$. Then by definition of boundary point we get $\forall \delta>0, B_\delta(y)\cap A^o \neq \emptyset$. Hence for any sequence of points in the interior, there always exist some radius of the open Ball such that, intersection remains non-empty. (Essentially, $||x-y||<\delta ,\forall x\in A^o$)

Now from our definition of the distance function: $d(x,y)\leq||x-y||<d(x,y)+\epsilon, \forall x\in A^o$, hence we can deduce $d(x,y)<\delta$, letting $\delta \rightarrow 0$, we get $d(x,y)=0$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my definition of boundary point is the following:
$y\in \partial A$ iff given $\delta>0$, $B_{\delta}(y)\cap A\neq \emptyset$ and $B_{\delta}(y)\cap A^{c} \neq \emptyset$.
In this case, can we still conclude that $B_{\delta}(y)\cap A^{o}\neq \emptyset$?

Comment: Yes, because a set could be open in that case $A=A^o$ , it could be closed, it which case $A=A^o \cup \partial{A}$ or it could be neither open nor closed in which case it will contain some of its boundary points and all its interior or it could be clopen in which case will again have all its boundary points and all its interior points, in all these cases $B_\delta (y)\cap A \neq \phi \Longrightarrow B_\delta (y) \cap A^o \neq \phi$